# Google Sheets-Match IDs in different tabs to fill column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with two tabs. Tab A has IDs and a place where I want to fill a column. Tab B has the Same IDs and the data I want to fill into Tab As blank column. I want to auto-populate the Tab A Column with the data from Tab Bs column.

In practice, I have a dataset (tab A) with place names and IDs, and a data set (tab b) with IDs and Population. I want the population to fill into Tab A based on the matching IDs.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want this: **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A); VLOOKUP(A2:A; 'Tab B'!A2:B; 2; 0); ))`**

which means that **`IF`** ID from **`Tab B`** is found in **`Tab A`**, formula will return **`2`** (second) column from range **`A:B`** of **`Tab B`** in sorted order based on IDs in **A** column of **`Tab A`** - hence that **`0`**

here is demo spreadsheet: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUesMmT8JVTb_tqfaxfn38EWmDs_emByD8tBvZA_TKk/edit#gid=0)**

[image]